# Encryption/decryption using publickey | Crypto Module | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt using a public key stored in a file. Here is the code:

```
encryptWithKey (toEncrypt, publicKeyPath) {
        var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(publicKeyPath, "utf8");
        var buffer = new Buffer(toEncrypt, 'utf8');
        var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
        return encrypted.toString("base64"); //converting it to base64 string
},
decryptWithKey (toDecrypt, publicKeyPath) {
        var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(publicKeyPath, "utf8");
        var b = new Buffer(toDecrypt, 'base64') // converting back to normal string from base 64 string
        var decrypted = crypto.publicDecrypt(publicKey, b);
        return decrypted.toString('utf8');
},
```

What I understand, is that I am first reading the Key into a string, using a buffer with UTF8 encoding, and ecrypting my text using public encrypt method. Now when I try to decrypt the same encrypted text using the decrypt method, I get the error

> RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01

I assume that there is some padding issues with my public key? But I am using the same public key for both. In Crypto.js, I read this under publicDecrypt Method:

> publicKey can be an object or a string. If publicKey is a string, it
>   is treated as the key with no passphrase and will use
>   RSA_PKCS1_PADDING.

And, this under publicEncrypt Method:

> publicKey can be an object or a string. If publicKey is a string, it
>   is treated as the key with no passphrase and will use
>   RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING.

Now, I need to use public key as a string, and the definition for encrypt and decrypt specify that the default padding used for these methods are different. So how can I do that so it accepts same padding?

Comment: You cannot decrypt with a public key, only a private key can decrypt... That's the whole purpose of using those types of keys. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/9021/public-key-cryptography-pkc

Comment: Ok, so does it mean I will need to create a private key from this public key to decrypt?

Comment: It'd be the opposite. Either use the private key that created that public key, or create a new public key with your private key...

Comment: On a side note, the documentation states that a private key can be used a public key, but not the opposite. Simply because the public key is made from the private key.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I will continue my research further. This public key is provided by a 3rd Party API providers, so I will not be able to decrypt my text with their key it means. I will need to create my own and then test. Thanks! But if it is not possible to decrypt using a public key, so why this method? https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicdecrypt_publickey_buffer

Comment: It came at the same time as privateEncrypt ... So I'm guessing it is for when it got encrypted with private key... The public key you have from your 3rd, is to be used with them, only. Use your own keys for your own work. Keys should be treated correctly... You do not let your house/car keys lay around everywhere, nor do you make hundreds of copy... Even tough the public key, is meant to be public, it will only work when interacting with its private pair.

Comment: Thank for clarification. I think it makes sense. You encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key from that private key. Thanks again :)

Comment: I am not sure how to close it, so if you can propose an answer, I will accept your solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might not fix the exact problem exposed in OP. The fact is that it is not possible to use a public key for both encryption and decryption. The encryption and decryption should be done using one public and one private key.

An exception to the rule is that using the private key for both actions is doable as a public key derives from the private key, and node can do it behind the scene.

Now, the fact that we are getting the error `RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01` might not be caused by this exactly. There is a good chance that it will not appear once the functions are used as intended. If it reappears that would mean the PADDING parameter is wrong, and playing a bit with the possible values will fix it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. It helped me understanding what I was doing wrong.